# Linking router from VPN to main network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, dd-wrt

So, here's what I have going on now:

Thomson Cable Modem ---> WAN port on D-Link N600 (IP 192.168.0.1 - DHCP 192.168.0.100-149) running stock D-link Firmware ---> Wan port on Linksys E1200 (IP 192.168.0.150 - DHCP 192.168.0.151-200) running DD-WRT, connected to a PPTP VPN.

Everything works great - But I can't access devices between the two routers, for example connected to the VPN router, I cannot airplay to my AppleTV on the main router. Devices on the same routers can see each other, but not what's connected to the other router.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll be the first to admit that I don't know as much as I'd like about networking, but I would put the routers on different subnets in an arrangement like this.

Comment: Is there a technical reason why I would do that? The DHCP is set on both to not overlap and both have different IP's. That was my first shot (192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2) but I had the same problem. Part of my thinking in merging them into the same subnet was assisting them in seeing each other. My guess is the VPN on the second router is the issue but unsure how to resolve.

Comment: The issue you are connecting the two routers together through one of the WAN ports. Those are specialized to hide the computers from the other router.  Connect the routers together via the LAN plugs and turn off DHCP on the Linksys.  The first router will assign it.

Comment: I haven't used a PPTP VPN before but I assume the VPN doesn't know to route packets intended for hosts 100-149 to the D-Link router. Devices 151-200 work because the DD-WRT router knows not to route those to the VPN tunnel. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @wbeard52 I don't believe the PPTP VPN on the second router will connect if it's not connected to the WAN port?

Comment: It will but you need to turn off DHCP and provide a static IP address for the second router.